# How can I best handle sessions in my RestController within Spring?

Tags: spring, session, spring-boot

I'm looking for suggestions on how to handle sessions more elegantly than my implementation below.

Basically I've written a `BaseController` that has a `handleSession()` routine that does the initial creation and subsequent reads from session data.  This session data is required to store various security information that I don't want to be reading on every hit for obvious performance reasons.  I also don't want to store this on the client, or I would just create a new request to pull the information back to Angular.

`CustomerController` implements this `handleSession()` call within each request.  This means I have to put it everywhere.

Is there a more graceful way to handle this?

*BaseController.java*

```
public abstract class BaseController {

    public Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public void handleSession(HttpSession session) {
        if (session.isNew()) {
            log.info("New session: " + session.getId());
            // TODO: write all session data here?
            session.setAttribute("Parm", "Value");
        } else {
            // TODO: read all session data here?
            log.info("Reused session: " + session.getId() + " Parm is set to: "
                    + session.getAttribute("Parm"));

        }
    }
}
```

*CustomerController.java*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/data/customer")
public class CustomerController extends BaseController {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @RequestMapping("")
    List<Customer> customers(HttpSession session) {
        handleSession(session);
        return customerRepository.getCustomers();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/{company}/{customer}/{division}")
    Customer customer(@PathVariable String company,
            @PathVariable String customer, @PathVariable String division,
            HttpSession session) {
        handleSession(session);
        return customerRepository.getCustomer(company, customer, division);
    }
}
```

Comment: What sort of session data? Generally speaking, REST clients are going to ignore your session cookie and make separate requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not following your specific needs exactly..but generally session initialization is a cross cutting concern, and cross cutting concerns are generally best handled as a servlet filter, not within each controller method.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can get HttpSession information with @Autowired in you Controller. If you pass session information as parameter, there will be chance that you will get security vulnerability finding for your application.

For this, use the approach below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/data/customer")
public class CustomerController extends BaseController {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private HttpSession httpSession;
```

You can remove HttpSession parameter from all your request mapping methods.

Comment: I m kinda new to spring and web stufs but 
if I autowire the HttpSession will this lead to have a shared sessionAttributes between all controllers ????

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb kind of, not exactly controllers but user session. Every user session is shared with all controllers, but the same controller with a different user will have a different session with different attributes, but persistent for that user session.